# Execute Linux command in bash script and write output to console with preservation of break lines

Tags: bash

I want a bash function that executes the given command, prints its output to the console and notifies me when the execution of the script finished. The function looks something like this:

```
n() {
  echo $($a)
  notify-send "Exexution of '$@' has finished."
}
```

When I run `n ls` I want the output the output of `ls` to be the same as if it was executed from the console. But instead it puts the output of `ls` on a single line.

```
$ n ls -la 
drwxr-xr-x 30 orangetux orangetux 4096 Jan 18 12:41 bundle drwxr-xr-x 2 orangetux orangetux 4096 Jan 9 22:23 colors
```

instead of:

```
$ ls
drwxr-xr-x 30 orangetux orangetux 4096 Jan 18 12:41 bundle
drwxr-xr-x  2 orangetux orangetux 4096 Jan  9 22:23 colors
```

How do I print the output of `n ls` like `ls`?

**EDIT**

Removed note about highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
n() { "$@"; echo "Execution of '$@' has finished."; }
```

i.e. don't use `echo $(...)` as whitespaces are stripped by shell without quotes.

You could also do:

```
echo "$($@)"
```

Comment: Line breaks are fixed now, thanks. But my terminal does not add highlighting so I can see the difference between symlinks, files and directories easily. Do know how to fix that?

Comment: Actually that worked for me when I did: `nl ls -la --color`. It showed all the colors on my OSX terminal.

Comment: I see that `ls` is an alias for `ls --color=tty`. When executed inside a script the alias is ignored apparently.

Comment: Yes I also guessed that because alias are't exported.